# Постоянно создаются фрагменты в ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Есть viewPager. К нему написан Адаптер.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
    RussianArtistFragment russianArtistFragment;
    ForeignArtistFragment foreignArtistFragment;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        russianArtistFragment = new RussianArtistFragment();
        foreignArtistFragment = new ForeignArtistFragment();

    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position==0){

            return RussianArtistFragment.newInstance();
        }
        if (position==1){
                return foreignArtistFragment;
        } else
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

У меня есть 4 табы. Если перехожу с первую на вторую или третью, потом опять на первую работает все нормально. Но если захожу на четвертую табу потом на первую, то в первой табе фрагмент пересоздается. У меня в этом фрагменте есть коллекция ArrayList. В которой храняться артисты. После пересоздания он заполняется ее повторно и у меня уже 2 одинаковых списка.

Помню была какая то функиця в PageAdapter которая делала сколько хранить в памяти Fragmentov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта
1.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Это позволит создавать и хранить не один фрагмент с каждой стороны от текущего, а больше (два в данном случае).

2. Записывать результат выполнения `RussianArtistFragment.newInstance()` и  `PageFragment.newInstance(position)` (инстанс фрагмента) в переменную при первом создании, и при следующем выдавать значение этой переменной, как работают `ListAdapter`'ы